# Sharepoint People Picker with arabic input

Tags: sharepoint, arabic, multilingual, sharepoint-online, peoplepicker

I've an requirement, that I need to implement corporate search in SharePoint online Page, and user should be able to search the employees in both English and arabic languages.

Corporate search with English has been done, no idea to implement arabic search.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the search results webpart from the search result page in the search center and open the .webpart file with a texteditor.

Then find a property called “DataProviderJSON” in the search results webpart. One of the values of this property is called “`FallbackLanguage`”  which by default is set to “`-1`″. You can set the value to the specific locale id which you would like to use for the search results, in your case would be 1025 for arabic language.

After changing the value just import the webpart again on the search results page in SharePoint.